# What does the statement "concatenating only if the object exists" mean?

Tags: python, pandas

```
pd.concat(g for _, g in grades.groupby("StudentID") if len(g) > 1)
```

I came across this "Concatenate only if the object exists" `pd.concat()` method where there's a for loop with an underscore along with an if condition. I don't have the dataset currently available, but it would be great if anyone could break this line for me, and help me understand it.

Comment: underscore basically tells python that it is a throwaway variable and won't be used (helps a little with performance) for example here the function would return two values (expected) but the first one won't be necessary. the if statement works as an if statement and in this case tells to append g to list only if length of g is bigger than one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `grades.groupby("StudentID")` is probably a tuple, so it has two values for example `(1,1)`. `for value1, value2 in grades.groupby("StudentID")` would give you these two values, but apparently, the value1 is not needed, so you add a `_` to save memory. The whole line basically means: Go through every object in `grades.groupby("StudentID")`, concat the first value to pd if it's longer than 1